# Python Benchmarking Spike in Execution Time

Tags: python

I've been having a very annoying problem with a more complex program, and constructed this much simpler program to figure out what is happening. I'm new to python, and memory issues baffle me (if in fact this is a memory issue) This code just executes and outputs the execution time for each While True loop:

```
# just iterates a bunch of times, timing how long it takes
def run_loops():

    curr_milliseconds_loop = time.time() * 1000

    for i in range(0,10000000):
        c = 1

    print("LOOP! MS=", time.time() * 1000 - curr_milliseconds_loop)


# starts my program
def start_program():

    while True:

        run_loops()
        gc.collect()

# start program in main
if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_program()
```

The problem is that there's a spike in execution time. I would say with this code, it happens maybe every 20 iterations on average, it its usually about 3x longer execution time for that loop. Heres some sample output from my terminal window, starting from the beginning

```
LOOP! MS= 239.360595703125
LOOP! MS= 236.3681640625
LOOP! MS= 238.360595703125
LOOP! MS= 242.3515625
LOOP! MS= 240.355224609375
LOOP! MS= 228.385009765625
LOOP! MS= 229.382568359375
LOOP! MS= 232.376220703125
LOOP! MS= 238.3603515625
LOOP! MS= 243.35205078125
LOOP! MS= 239.340576171875
LOOP! MS= 238.332763671875
LOOP! MS= 226.39404296875
LOOP! MS= 230.38330078125
LOOP! MS= 226.393798828125
LOOP! MS= 230.383544921875
LOOP! MS= 236.400634765625
LOOP! MS= 232.376953125
LOOP! MS= 230.386474609375
LOOP! MS= 234.37890625
LOOP! MS= 233.3740234375
LOOP! MS= 247.345458984375
LOOP! MS= 240.359130859375
LOOP! MS= 245.3427734375
LOOP! MS= 227.357666015625
LOOP! MS= 232.3779296875
LOOP! MS= 224.399169921875
LOOP! MS= 230.383056640625
LOOP! MS= 224.39892578125
LOOP! MS= 232.378173828125
LOOP! MS= 228.38818359375
LOOP! MS= 230.3828125
LOOP! MS= 227.426513671875
LOOP! MS= 245.34619140625
LOOP! MS= 246.343017578125
LOOP! MS= 229.384765625
LOOP! MS= 225.396240234375
LOOP! MS= 229.38623046875
LOOP! MS= 229.385986328125
LOOP! MS= 232.3779296875
LOOP! MS= 328.12158203125   <-- spike
LOOP! MS= 233.37548828125
LOOP! MS= 229.385986328125
LOOP! MS= 230.3828125
LOOP! MS= 228.388427734375
LOOP! MS= 231.381103515625
LOOP! MS= 234.37255859375
LOOP! MS= 231.380615234375
LOOP! MS= 227.39111328125
LOOP! MS= 247.338134765625
LOOP! MS= 229.3857421875
LOOP! MS= 237.393310546875
LOOP! MS= 377.954345703125
LOOP! MS= 233.37548828125
LOOP! MS= 230.383544921875
LOOP! MS= 232.3779296875
LOOP! MS= 232.378173828125
LOOP! MS= 245.376953125
LOOP! MS= 250.326904296875
LOOP! MS= 233.37939453125
LOOP! MS= 238.365234375
LOOP! MS= 232.378662109375
LOOP! MS= 228.399658203125
LOOP! MS= 235.3701171875
LOOP! MS= 228.388427734375
LOOP! MS= 374.997314453125
LOOP! MS= 483.706298828125   <-- spike
LOOP! MS= 354.0517578125
LOOP! MS= 228.387939453125
LOOP! MS= 233.375244140625
LOOP! MS= 228.38818359375
LOOP! MS= 233.37451171875
LOOP! MS= 259.30615234375
LOOP! MS= 236.366943359375
LOOP! MS= 229.385986328125
LOOP! MS= 233.37451171875
LOOP! MS= 230.383056640625
LOOP! MS= 234.37255859375
LOOP! MS= 229.3857421875
LOOP! MS= 232.3779296875
LOOP! MS= 238.3955078125
LOOP! MS= 236.36328125
LOOP! MS= 238.365478515625
LOOP! MS= 240.357421875
LOOP! MS= 235.370361328125
LOOP! MS= 251.3291015625
LOOP! MS= 249.32568359375
LOOP! MS= 252.331787109375
LOOP! MS= 232.3818359375
LOOP! MS= 245.340087890625
LOOP! MS= 251.330810546875
LOOP! MS= 224.39794921875
LOOP! MS= 232.37841796875
LOOP! MS= 227.3916015625
LOOP! MS= 244.38037109375
LOOP! MS= 253.295166015625
LOOP! MS= 253.323974609375
LOOP! MS= 245.339111328125
LOOP! MS= 241.35693359375
LOOP! MS= 242.35302734375
LOOP! MS= 245.340576171875
LOOP! MS= 239.32763671875
LOOP! MS= 249.33447265625
LOOP! MS= 248.304443359375
LOOP! MS= 233.37353515625
LOOP! MS= 231.379638671875
LOOP! MS= 239.39111328125
LOOP! MS= 248.334716796875
LOOP! MS= 241.398193359375
LOOP! MS= 242.35009765625
LOOP! MS= 251.359619140625
LOOP! MS= 257.312255859375
LOOP! MS= 263.262939453125
LOOP! MS= 229.38671875
LOOP! MS= 247.369873046875
LOOP! MS= 234.373046875
LOOP! MS= 243.349609375
LOOP! MS= 238.330078125
LOOP! MS= 250.325927734375
LOOP! MS= 262.271728515625
LOOP! MS= 236.37744140625
LOOP! MS= 242.346923828125
LOOP! MS= 241.330810546875
LOOP! MS= 351.059326171875
LOOP! MS= 240.329833984375
LOOP! MS= 248.3330078125
LOOP! MS= 253.322998046875
LOOP! MS= 242.347412109375
LOOP! MS= 230.383056640625
LOOP! MS= 239.36328125
LOOP! MS= 241.35302734375
LOOP! MS= 247.339111328125
LOOP! MS= 245.343505859375
LOOP! MS= 249.331787109375
LOOP! MS= 243.318115234375
LOOP! MS= 256.3134765625
LOOP! MS= 236.374267578125
LOOP! MS= 258.27734375
LOOP! MS= 259.30224609375
LOOP! MS= 250.362060546875
LOOP! MS= 245.3447265625
LOOP! MS= 245.341796875
LOOP! MS= 248.334228515625
LOOP! MS= 241.354248046875
LOOP! MS= 254.31982421875
LOOP! MS= 252.32861328125
LOOP! MS= 254.350830078125
LOOP! MS= 250.322021484375
LOOP! MS= 254.29248046875
LOOP! MS= 233.3779296875
LOOP! MS= 243.346923828125
LOOP! MS= 262.267578125
LOOP! MS= 323.16162109375
LOOP! MS= 244.34423828125
LOOP! MS= 254.32080078125
LOOP! MS= 356.048095703125
LOOP! MS= 238.363037109375
LOOP! MS= 241.359130859375
LOOP! MS= 254.280517578125
LOOP! MS= 225.3994140625
LOOP! MS= 480.714111328125   <-- spike
LOOP! MS= 236.3701171875
LOOP! MS= 233.37109375
LOOP! MS= 236.36962890625
LOOP! MS= 246.364990234375
LOOP! MS= 249.33154296875
LOOP! MS= 247.333251953125
LOOP! MS= 246.34228515625
LOOP! MS= 256.31689453125
LOOP! MS= 251.3271484375
LOOP! MS= 242.354248046875
LOOP! MS= 247.34716796875
LOOP! MS= 251.322509765625
LOOP! MS= 240.36279296875
LOOP! MS= 243.350341796875
LOOP! MS= 243.3505859375
LOOP! MS= 256.28759765625
LOOP! MS= 246.341552734375
LOOP! MS= 262.34228515625
LOOP! MS= 249.30029296875
LOOP! MS= 253.322021484375
LOOP! MS= 263.263916015625
LOOP! MS= 236.366943359375
LOOP! MS= 246.341796875
LOOP! MS= 245.37646484375
LOOP! MS= 248.330078125
LOOP! MS= 239.360595703125
LOOP! MS= 252.3271484375
LOOP! MS= 260.305419921875
LOOP! MS= 272.313232421875
LOOP! MS= 238.364501953125
LOOP! MS= 238.363525390625
LOOP! MS= 243.34912109375
LOOP! MS= 238.330322265625
LOOP! MS= 255.28564453125
LOOP! MS= 266.289794921875
LOOP! MS= 261.333251953125
LOOP! MS= 261.268798828125
LOOP! MS= 256.3056640625
LOOP! MS= 246.342529296875
LOOP! MS= 248.3037109375
LOOP! MS= 251.29541015625
LOOP! MS= 250.298095703125
LOOP! MS= 240.35693359375
LOOP! MS= 259.339111328125
LOOP! MS= 250.361572265625
LOOP! MS= 256.280029296875
LOOP! MS= 235.368896484375
LOOP! MS= 243.34912109375
LOOP! MS= 241.35498046875
LOOP! MS= 254.351806640625
LOOP! MS= 254.353759765625
LOOP! MS= 261.3017578125
LOOP! MS= 252.29248046875
LOOP! MS= 260.304931640625
LOOP! MS= 254.287841796875
LOOP! MS= 246.338134765625
LOOP! MS= 358.0498046875
LOOP! MS= 1162.85546875     <-- spike
LOOP! MS= 784.875244140625
LOOP! MS= 232.34619140625
LOOP! MS= 239.359619140625
LOOP! MS= 250.3349609375
LOOP! MS= 229.385498046875
LOOP! MS= 233.375244140625
LOOP! MS= 235.3984375
LOOP! MS= 240.3583984375
LOOP! MS= 237.362548828125
LOOP! MS= 240.322998046875
LOOP! MS= 230.385009765625
LOOP! MS= 232.40234375
LOOP! MS= 235.36328125
LOOP! MS= 242.346923828125
LOOP! MS= 410.875            <-- spike
LOOP! MS= 239.35986328125
LOOP! MS= 238.36279296875
LOOP! MS= 241.35498046875
LOOP! MS= 251.33154296875
LOOP! MS= 239.35986328125
LOOP! MS= 238.360595703125
LOOP! MS= 234.3408203125
LOOP! MS= 230.383056640625
LOOP! MS= 235.369873046875
LOOP! MS= 230.3828125
LOOP! MS= 232.4052734375
LOOP! MS= 242.3828125
LOOP! MS= 249.33447265625
LOOP! MS= 252.293212890625
LOOP! MS= 264.321044921875
LOOP! MS= 254.32177734375
LOOP! MS= 256.3125
LOOP! MS= 255.318603515625
LOOP! MS= 261.33251953125
LOOP! MS= 255.35009765625
LOOP! MS= 251.2958984375
LOOP! MS= 228.392333984375
LOOP! MS= 769.913818359375
LOOP! MS= 1191.76220703125
LOOP! MS= 364.056396484375
LOOP! MS= 236.3701171875
LOOP! MS= 243.349853515625
LOOP! MS= 243.31640625
LOOP! MS= 235.33837890625
LOOP! MS= 256.314453125
LOOP! MS= 244.31494140625
LOOP! MS= 237.328125
LOOP! MS= 244.373046875
LOOP! MS= 251.328369140625
LOOP! MS= 257.344970703125
LOOP! MS= 247.339111328125
LOOP! MS= 253.3125
LOOP! MS= 249.33349609375
LOOP! MS= 254.318603515625
LOOP! MS= 234.404296875
LOOP! MS= 247.339111328125
LOOP! MS= 231.376708984375
LOOP! MS= 239.355224609375
LOOP! MS= 238.330078125
LOOP! MS= 243.3828125
LOOP! MS= 247.33837890625
LOOP! MS= 245.342041015625
LOOP! MS= 239.3603515625
LOOP! MS= 252.293701171875
LOOP! MS= 228.387939453125
LOOP! MS= 234.372802734375
LOOP! MS= 229.385498046875
LOOP! MS= 240.39013671875
LOOP! MS= 242.347900390625
LOOP! MS= 246.333251953125
LOOP! MS= 243.34765625
LOOP! MS= 252.32568359375
LOOP! MS= 249.33642578125
LOOP! MS= 254.346923828125
```

These spikes are extremely annoying, it happens in  my more complex program too, where they are much more significant because there's more code. What is the problem here? Is it my computer? Is it a garbage collection issue? I've tried using gc.collect() and as you can see there are still spikes, but i'm pretty certain without gc.collect() the spikes are more frequent. How can I get rid of these spikes altogether? Even if execution time rises slightly, no spikes is preferred. Any help is appreciated thanks. The code is running in the interpreter, its not compiled.

P.S. I'm very new to python, so please explain it to me like I'm a 6-year old. Thanks

Comment: your computer has a lot of responsibilities other than running python as well. This could easily be a process outside python affecting things, and could literally be anything.

Comment: Read up on cpu scheduling

Comment: ok thanks for the input